# Cordova refresh javascript

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, visual-studio-cordova

Hi I'm wondering is it possible to host the javascript files of Cordova project on a hosting server, and call

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

to get the latest version of javascript from the server?

Or is there a better way to accomplish this? Waiting for apple's approval is taking too much time.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not totally in the way that you meant to do this. But, take a look at [Ionic Deploy](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-deploy-alpha-update-your-app-without-waiting/):

> Ionic Deploy lets you update your app on demand for any changes that do not require binary modifications, saving you days, or even weeks, of wait time. You can roll back to a previous version of your app, automatically apply updates, and control every aspect of the upgrade. Being able to make live changes to an app allows you to work with your designer or other team members to collaborate in real time, empowering you to get immediate feedback while you develop and make changes on the fly.

You can learn more about how to implement this by following the official guide: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-from-scratch.